# Tautology and logical consequence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given 
$$
L =\{p_1,...,p_6\}
$$
how many equivalence classes of propositional terms $t$ are there such that 
$$
p_1 \lor \lnot p_1 \models t
$$

I know that the first part is a tautology but can't wrap my head around the question / or around the understanding of the logic.

Any help / direction appreciated

Comment: Tautological consequence: $t$ must be true in every valuation $v$ such that $v(p_1 \lor \lnot p_1)$ is true. But this one is a tautology, i.e. true in every valuation; thus also $t$ must be true in every valuation, i.e. *tautology*.

Comment: How do I then get from there to the number of equivalence classes of $t$?

Comment: What are "propositional terms" ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_formula

Comment: So "propositional term" means *formula*...  You are speaking of "equivalence classes"; they are defined with respect to an *equivalence relation*. What is the equivalence relation defined on propositional formulas that you are using ?